# Is there a way to display the Windows 8 Task Manager Performace tab data on my desktop?

Tags: windows-8, desktop, task-manager

I'm generally a mac user and when using my mac I use a little piece of software called iStat Pro that shows me what's going on with my machine at all times.  I have come to love that.

Recently I've had to do a bit more work on Windows 8 machines and would like to have the same capability.  There are some third party solutions that are okay but I really like the native Task Manager Performance tab.  Is there any way that I can expose that data with the graphs etc displayed right on my desktop or somewhere else that's more visible?  It would be awesome if it were possible.  Anyone know how to expose that on the desktop at startup?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Is there some kind of widget for lack of a better word that could be exposed?  I don't need the whole task manager.  It would be nice just to expose the Performance Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, open the Task Manager an leave it open. You can schedule it to be opened at logon. It will remember what tab you had and where it was on the desktop when you closed it. It even has an "Always On Top" option. :)

Otherwise, there are a ton of widgets for showing you that/similar info (I use the [Moo0 System Monitor](http://www.moo0.com/?top=http://www.moo0.com/software/SystemMonitor/) myself).

If you don't like the widgets you find, all the info offered by the performance tab can be accessed via WMI ([Windows Management Instrumentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx)), which you can script/program against if you wish to make something custom.